# Why do I keep getting error code 38197, status 403 while integrating Amadeus on flutterflow app

Tags: http-status-code-403, amadeus, flutterflow

My first attempt to integrate Amadeus API with my flutterflow app has been chaotic. I got my API key and secret key (test mode) and input it using the Get API. I entered the API key as clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxx and Secret as clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.

The query parameters as shown below:

[image: The query parameters]

On testing out the API call, I get below error:

[image: Test API Call error]

Kindly assist.

I have looked at the documentation and tried to change the way I input the API Key and Secret Key but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The API key and API secret shouldn't be added in this API that you try to call.

With the API key and API secret you need to generate an access token by calling the authorization endpoint `POST https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token`, and then pass the access token in the Headers of the API you try to call.

Check the [authorization guide](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/API-Keys/authorization/) with all the details.